# Copy Access query result into excel using docmd.outputto

Tags: excel, output, vba

I tried to use the "docmd.openquery" to run an existing query and it was successful. But when I tried to output the query result into excel using "docmd.outputto" method , it gave me application-defined and object-defined error. Could anyone help resolve the issue? Here is the code below.

```
Sub run_access_query()
    Dim accessapp As Object    
    Set accessapp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    accessapp.Visible = False

    accessapp.Opencurrentdatabase "U:\myAccess Databases\testdatabase.mdb"

    With accessapp.DoCmd
        .SetParameter "input_no", "20032967590"
        .OpenQuery "test_query"               
        .OutputTo acOutputquery, "test_query"                     
    End With
    Set accessapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)

Comment: I tried, it gave the same error.

Comment: Please post the code you used for `TransferSpreadsheet` I suspect your arguments are off... And what line did the error occur on?

Comment: Hi Scott, sure, please check it below, thanks a lot for your help.                                                                  `.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "test_query", "I:\Documents\Access\test.xlsx", True`

Comment: It didn't give which line the error on. I was running the vba code in an excel workbook. The problem was definitely from the `docmd.Trasnferspreadsheet` as I marked it as a comment, no error would be displayed.

Comment: If you run the code line-by-line ([Step Through VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)), which line does the error occur on? Or when the error appears and you hit debug, which line is highlighted in yellow? And if you marked it as a comment, how do you expect it to run the code?

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried to run the code line-by-line hitting F8 each time, and the error occurred exactly after the `.TransferSpreadsheet` line was yellow highlighted. I marked it with comment and the code had no error anymore.

Comment: my apologies, I just noticed your using `.mdb`... `TransferSpreadsheet` only works in 2010 and above. :( ... can you convert to `accdb`

Comment: No problem, I'm working with 2010 version. I can try to convert to accdb and see what'll happen. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Scott. I tried to convert to accdb and problem was still there. I even tried to create a new accdb database. Please note that the code is Excel-VBA code, I noticed that most people use `TransferSpreadsheet` in Acess-VBA, do you think that'll be a problem? Thanks.

Comment: No. That is not a problem, except that Excel might not recognize the Access constant `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12`. You may need the enumeration for that. I will play with it when I back in office in the morning. I am sure it's just a matter of syntax or possibly the enum.